# openSSL read/write thread safety

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety, libssl

We have service using `openSSL` version `1.0.2h` in multi threaded environment.

First thread runs blocking read, the other one is doing periodical writes.

It crashes from time to time somewhere inside `libssl.so` in `SSL_write` function. Code calling `SSL_write` looks absolutely legal, it operates with buffer allocated on stack of the calling function. Also crash is very rare which suggests it might be race condition.

I found the following [article](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/) saying that using a single `SSL` object in two threads, one each for reading and writing is not safe, though `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback` is set. Is that correct? If yes, than what is the suggested way to resolve this? If I block `mutex` on a blocking read, I will not able to write.

Comment: Use two SSL objects?

Comment: for a single connection?

Answer (score 0):

We suggest modifying the timeout thresholds.

Tracing and debugging race condition is difficult and eventually you will have to change  timeout and/or buffer parameters. Better study these parameters right now.

Comment: I didn't really get how this will help to resolve race condition if it really exists? I tried to do simultaneous reads and writes in infinite loop and application worked perfectly fine for a whole day. I guess it's something else.